# Execute SSIS package with Proxy - Could not get proxy data for Proxy_id

Tags: sql-server, ssis, proxy, ssms, sql-server-agent

I am trying to execute an SSIS package using a Credential and Proxy - it works fine with a user with a SysAdmin role and we want to avoid using SysAdmin.

I have followed all the steps to create a Credential and Proxy and set up the permissions for the user in msdb and SSISDb tables and in the Security -> logins

I have followed the steps in the below links as a guide:-

- [Run an SSIS Package Under a Different Account](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/run-an-ssis-package-under-a-different-account)
- [Running a SSIS Package from SQL Server Agent Using a Proxy Account](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/)
- [SQL Server Agent - Running SSIS Package with Proxy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62264/sql-server-agent-running-ssis-package-with-proxy)

Proxy -> properties -> Principals

[image]

When I run the job I get the below error - looks like a permission issue

> Unable to start execution of step 1 (Reason: Could not get proxy data for proxy_id = 198_. The step failed.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the login type of the proxy account (Windows or SQL Server user)?

Comment: @Hadi it's a SQL Server login

Comment: try using a windows account instead. As I know proxy accounts need to have a windows authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, you are using an **SQL Server login** as a proxy account. While in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15) they mentioned that:

> SQL Server Agent proxies use credentials to store information about **Windows user accounts**. The user-specified in the credential must have "Access this computer from the network" permission (SeNetworkLogonRight) on the computer on which SQL Server is running.

I suggest following one of the following articles to set up an SQL Server agent proxy:

- [Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Setting Up Your SQL Server Agent Correctly](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/)

Comment: Created a Windows User and it worked fine